# Homebrew not accepting valid options

Tags: macos, homebrew

I've built a script to install a bunch of packages with homebrew. The script's available [here](https://github.com/modestotech/dotfiles/blob/ff1cda0fa6b7d3ff76bb1dafcebe2bcfa8e788e6/macos/installApplicationsWithBrew.sh).

When installing packages that has options, such as `--with-default-names` I get a warning like this:

```
warning: gnu-indent: this formula has no --with-default-names option so it will be ignored!
```

If I check the [site](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gnu-indent), `--with-default-names` is a valid option.

If I run brew info gnu-indent I get the following output (nothing about `--with-default-names`).

```
gnu-indent: stable 2.2.12 (bottled)
C code prettifier
https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/
/usr/local/Cellar/gnu-indent/2.2.12 (47 files, 598.3KB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2019-02-02 at 10:18:03
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/gnu-indent.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: gettext ✔
==> Caveats
GNU "indent" has been installed as "gindent".
If you need to use it as "indent", you can add a "gnubin" directory
to your PATH from your bashrc like:

    PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-indent/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
==> Analytics
install: 1,421 (30 days), 3,893 (90 days), 14,931 (365 days)
install_on_request: 1,325 (30 days), 3,584 (90 days), 13,848 (365 days)
build_error: 0 (30 days)
```

I've tried `brew doctor` (no warnings), [uninstall](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ) Homebrew, and different syntaxes, without prevail. I've also used each command directly on the command line (outside the script), with the same results. 
Note that I get error for all packages for which I use options.

Comment: If the formula does not list this option, what makes you think it's a valid option to pass?

Comment: Check the [link](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gnu-indent) above. There the option is listed. It's also used in several guides on how to install GNU command line tools on macOS, such as [this](https://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/).

Comment: The option obviously does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Options are going away](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/31510) for core formulae.

You could use `brew edit` to edit the formula to your liking. You might have to remove the `bottle`.

Comment: Yes, that's seems to be the case. Confusing for me as I'm not very into how HomeBrew works, as the options are still among the most downloaded on the formulae.brew.sh site. The options must have been removed recently.

Comment: The option was removed on [Jan 5](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/e560394b30c3aa8aff7d59257e4cb2c6aafbf2cd), that’s why installs are still showing up in the 30-days statistic.

Comment: Ok, I've searched now and can see that the option `--with-default-names` has been removed by the same time. Now I've learnt some about HomeBrew at least.

Comment: A [link](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/search?q=default-names+created%3A2019-01-01..2019-01-10&unscoped_q=default-names+created%3A2019-01-01..2019-01-10&type=Commits) to the affected commits in the beginning of January 2019, if anyone's interested.